# Customizing a modern page using SpFx

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-online, spfx

I want to transform a classic site into a modern experience and I have the following customization, done on a classic list form.

The page contains two Webparts:

1. `XsltListViewWebPart` to display the list of items
2. `ContentEditorWebPart` to fetch some summary data

Problem :

The SPFx extension used to replace the default rendering of the list works **only** on the `allitems.aspx` page (it is not working on my custom page which contains `ListWebpart`)

I need to know how to be able to make SPFx extension working on that `ListWebpart`.
Or if it is possible to add a client side webpart inside my `allitems.apx` page.

Answer (score 0):

We can't 'Edit' OOB modern list view currently.

When you add list view to a modern page, you could deploy [react-script-editor](https://github.com/SharePoint/sp-dev-fx-webparts/tree/master/samples/react-script-editor) to your tenant so you could add this webpart to modern page which works like script editor webpart in classic view.